# Search Keys and Replace Values in XML

Tags: python, xml, shell, replace, sed

I have an xml file which looks like below

```
<name>abcdefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
```

I am trying to write a script using sed to search for the tag "abcdefg" and then **replace the corresponding value** "123456" but unfortunately I am not able to find a logic to achieve above.
 Need help!

Comment: [beautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a good way to read tags from html.

Comment: What does your structure look like? Is it `<item><key>k1</key><value>v1</value><item><key>k2</key><value>v2</value></item>`? Or is it `<items><key>k1</key><value>v1</value><key>k2</key><value>v2</value></items>`? We can't provide a semantically-aware answer if we don't know the structure.

Comment: ...and, to be clear, an answer that *isn't* semantically-aware will be necessarily buggy: It won't be able to distinguish between comments and CDATA sections and literal content.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data used:

```
 cat key
<name>abcdaaefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
<name>abcdefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
<name>abcdaaefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
```

`sed` solution:

```
 sed '/abcdefg/!b;n;c<value>OLA<value>' key

<name>abcdaaefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
<name>abcdefg</name>
<value>OLA<value>
<name>abcdaaefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
```

For doing changes in file.

```
sed -i.bak '/abcdefg/!b;n;c<value>OLA<value>' key
```

`awk` Solution:

```
awk '/abcdefg/ {print $0;getline;sub(/>.*</,">ola<")} {print $0}' key
<name>abcdaaefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
<name>abcdefg</name>
<value>ola</value>
<name>abcdaaefg</name>
<value>123456</value>
```

Search for a line containing `abcdefg` and then do following actions:
1. print that line,
2.move to next line and replace the value inside html tag to something else.  Here , I have replaced `123456` with `ola`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the quick reply. But how do I replace the text in the file.

Comment: use `sed -i` ,this is called in place replacement and will do changes in your original file. If you want to keep backup of your file then `sed -i.bak`

Comment: To improve answer you could clarify `'/abcdefg/!b;n;c<value>OLA<value>'`

Comment: That `getline` will fail in cryptic ways given various input files and will make future enhancements difficult (e.g. try adding a debugging `print` for every input line that contains a number and notice you have to duplicate it) and so it's generally best avoided except in a very few specific cases where it adds some real value. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have tag->value pairs in your data it's a good idea to create a tag->value array in your code:

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' '{tag=$2; v[tag]=$3} tag=="value" && v["name"]=="abcdefg" {sub(/>.*</,">blahblah<")} 1' file
<name>abcdefg</name>
<value>blahblah</value>
```

Comment: This code isn't really well-behaved from an XML-compliance perspective. The assumption of one element per line, for instance, means that this will break badly for a huge array of well-formed documents; there's also no recognition of whether content is commented out.  Moreover, in XML, there are circumstances where `<`s can and will be literal rather than syntax -- `CDATA` sections, for instance.

Comment: Agreed. It seems like most questions we get here about parsing XML are really about parsing XML used in a very restricted way and so awk or other solutions are usually adequate BUT you could make that same case for not quoting shell variables, etc. so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML-aware tool. This will make your approach far more robust: It means that tiny changes in the textual description (like added or removed newlines, or extra attributes added to a preexisting element) won't break your script.

Assuming that your input's structure looks like this (with being under a single parent item, here called `item`, defining the relationship between a `name` and a `value`):

```
<config>
  <item><name>abcdef</name><value>123456</value></item>
  <item><name>fedcba</name><value>654321</value></item>
</config>
```

...you can edit it like so:

```
 # edit the value under an item having name "abcdef"
 xmlstarlet ed -u '//item[name="abcdef"]/value' -v "new-value"
```

---

If instead it's like this (with ordering between name/value pairs describing their relationship):

```
<config>
  <name>abcdef</name><value>123456</value>
  <name>fedcba</name><value>654321</value>
</config>
```

...then you can edit it like so:

```
# update the value immediately following a name of "abcdef"
xmlstarlet ed -u '//name[. = "abcdef"]/following-sibling::value[1]' -v new-value
```